# How to get notified when controller presents and dismisses popup

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `vc: MyUIViewController`. Under some conditions it may present a modal popup. I do not have direct control on when and why it happens.

At any moment I can find out if it presents anything checking `vc.presentedViewController != nil`.

What I want is to be notified that presentation begins and ends (dismisses). Is there any callback I could subscribe to?

Please note that I know nothing about popup (presented controller). I do not know its type and cannot modify its code.

Comment: That's a rather abstract question.... *"I know nothing about popup (presented controller)"* -- have you incorporated 3rd-party code which you allow to take over your app, without knowing what, when or why it does so?

Comment: @DonMag Yes. The app has a 3rd-party routing framework. When router is asked to show popup, it looks for the topmost controller in the view hierarchy. It may find my controller and present popup over it.

Comment: Well, I don't believe I've ever used a 3rd-party framework without the source code... I don't know what you're using, but I'd be hesitant to incorporate something that didn't at least give me a delegate to let me know what it's doing. Kinda beside the point, though. You *could* try overriding `present` and `dismiss`.